# Tableau, calcular diferencia en días horas y minutos de dos fechas. DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, tableau

Estoy trabajando en tableau y quiero obtener la diferencia en días, horas y minutos. Estoy usando DateDiff, casi todo sale bien, solo en algunos casos no me está contabilizando correctamente, por ejemplo, tengo **19:51 a 00:00** aquí me debería de dar **4 horas, 9 minutos** y me está dando una hora de más y lo mismo para la hora de **13:59 a 14:01** me da como resultado *1 hora,  2 minutos*, y solo debería de mostrarme **0 horas, 2 minutos**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo que estoy usando

```
STR(DATEDIFF('day', [Inicio de Falla], [Fecha resolucion falla IfNull])) + ' días, ' +
STR(DATEDIFF('hour', [Inicio de Falla], [Fecha resolucion falla IfNull]) % 24) + ' horas, ' +
STR(DATEDIFF('minute', [Inicio de Falla], [Fecha resolucion falla IfNull]) % 60) + ' minutos'
```

Alguna sugerencia para poder solucionar este error.

Saludos.

Comment: Saludos Daniel. Podrías ser tan amable de mostrar con mas detalle los casos donde te muestra diferencia errónea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En base a lo que publicas, diría que el problema es que `datediff()` no ve otra cosa más que lo que le pides. Así, `datediff(hour)` entre `13:59` y `14:01` solo ve `13` vs `14` y nos da una diferencia de 1, cuando en realidad solo han pasado 3 minutos.

Si observas tus resultados, el cálculo de días también es incorrecto. En el primer registro solo ha transcurrido un día y algunas horas, pero tu resultado dice que han transcurrido dos días.

Mi recomendación sería sacar todos los valores a partir de la diferencia en minutos, haciendo la aritmética correspondiente.

Por ejemplo, si sacas la diferencia en minutos y la divides dentro de los 1440 minutos que tiene un día, te da la diferencia en días. Así, habría que ir *arrastrando* el cálculo hasta tener solamente los minutos.

Básicamente, repetir el cálculo que harías en este pseudo-código:

```
total_minutos = DateDiff(minute, inicio, fin);
dias = total_minutos / 1440;
minutos_restantes = total_minutos % 1440
horas = minutos_restantes / 60
minutos = minutos_restantes % 60
```

Esto, en SQL vendría a ser algo similar a lo siguiente:

```sql
  STR(DATEDIFF('minute', [Inicio de Falla], [Fecha resolucion falla IfNull]) / 14400) + ' días, ' 
+ STR((DATEDIFF('minute', [Inicio de Falla], [Fecha resolucion falla IfNull]) % 14400) / 60) + ' horas, ' 
+ STR(DATEDIFF('minute', [Inicio de Falla], [Fecha resolucion falla IfNull]) % 60) + ' minutos '
```